# C# : getting folder name when right click on it

Tags: c#, contextmenu, directory

I am  developing a windows application, I need to get the Folder name while right clicking on the Folder to do some operations on it .

So far I did  the following :

1. Made a registry subkey in HKKEY_CLASS_ROOT\Folder\shell\(my program name)
2. Made a registry subkey of my program name\command [the path of my program]

now I made the registry key to be displayed in folder context menu. And in my application I did the following :

1- in program.cs

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 p = new Form1();
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            p.pathkey = args[0];
        }
        Application.Run(p);
    }
```

2- in my form1 :

```
    private string _pathkey;
    public string pathkey
    {
        get { return _pathkey; }
        set { _pathkey = value; }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (this.pathkey != null)
        {
           textBox1.Text=pathkey;
        }
    }
```

finally :

now when I right click on a folder lets say for example called NEW. then textbox3.text = C:\NEW , so far it works fine but if the folder name is New Folder then textbox3.text = C:\New only not C:\New Folder and that is my problem if args.length > 0 it does only display the the lenght 0 not the full path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563516/um-proggy-not-worky/1563668#1563668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `%0` in the registry in quotes to force the entire path to be treated as a single argument.
Otherwise, the spaces are treated as argument separators.

You could also call  `String.Join(" ", args)` to manually recombine all of the arguments, but the first way is better.

Comment: Wow man , it really worked , man very very very big thanks i really did a big search on that , thanks again , and by the way i put the %1 in double quotes not %0 and it also worked . thanks very much