# C# : capturing the file and path of a file when right I right click on the file

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a windows application with c#. I need to get the file and folder name when I right click on a file to use for other functions. Right now I have made the registry keys to get my application running.

When I right click on a file (word, ppt, txt, etc) my context menu shows the option I added, Set Perm/ When that is selected my windows application opens up. In a text box on the form, I want to display the full file name and path of the file the user clicked on. Is there a way to do that?

I've added %0 and %1 in the registry to then end of the arguument to launch my app, but it does not work. I've tried `h:\temp\myapp.exe %1` and `h:\temp\myapp.exe %0`.  Putting the `%1` or `%0` in quotes did not change anything.

I am in Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2017. Searching brought me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964871/c-sharp-getting-folder-name-when-right-click-on-it), but it has not answered my problem yet.

Comment: It would be great idea if you showed us your app code and registry definitions...

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you're asking, 
to have the path passed in the register,

```
void Main(string[] args)
```

the Path class has some useful methods to get to the folder and the string of a string

```
 Path.GetFullPath("the path")
```

sometimes path is args[0](when you drag the file on icon), but in your case you have to iuse args[1].

I hope I understand what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The question  referenced earlier did provide the answer. I was having issues with the form I was using. After working it with for a while I must have really messed it up. I created a new form and used it, using the code provided in that post i referenced.